# Number of legs and heads from Horse and Men in Prolog - RIDDLE

Tags: prolog

I am currently trying to solve a riddle:

> "How many men and horses have 8 heads and 20 feet?"

As I am trying to solve this question with Prolog, my attempt was:

```
puzzle(M,H,M+H,M*2 + H*4).
```

And then running:

```
puzzle(M, H,8,20).
```

Unfortunately, swipl just returns `false`.

Can anybody say, why prolog is not working as I was expecting?

To anyone that is interested in a working solution:

```
horsemen(Man, Horse, Heads, Legs) :-
   between(0, Legs, Man),
   between(0, Legs, Horse),
   Legs is 2*Man + 4*Horse, Heads is Man + Horse.
```

Anyway, I can't really understand, why the easier solution is not working.

Comment: By generalizing your query `?- puzzle(M,H,8,20).` you get the query `?- puzzle(M,H, Heads, Feet).` which has `Heads = M+H, Feet = M*2+H*4` as answer.

Comment: This is kind of a perfect problem for clpfd; entering this will find the solution for you: `M #> 0, H #> 0, M + H #= 8, M*2 + H*4 #= 20, label([M,H]).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your expression like this:

```
puzzleSimple(M,M+2).
```

Prolog will return **true** for a statement like this :

```
puzzleSimple(3,3+2). or puzzleSimple(M,M+2).
```

But it will return **false** for `puzzleSimple(3,5).` What you see here is that, prolog will not execute the `M+2`as an arithmetic operation but rather use it in pattern matching. For arithmetic operations, you need to use the `is` keyword. For example:

```
puzzleSimple(M,V):-
    V is M + 2.
```

This code will return **true** for `puzzleSimple(3,5).` So, when you try to directly use 
`puzzle(M,H,M+H,M*2 + H*4).` and call `puzzle(M, H,8,20).`
It returns false, because the pattern is not matching.

You can also modify the code to this:

```
puzzle(M,H,X,Y):-
    X is M+H,
    Y is M*2 + H*4.
```

Now it will be correct in the sense of pattern matching and arithmetic operations. However, when you again call `puzzle(M, H,8,20).` You will see an `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated` error. Why? Because you tried to do an arithmetic operation with a variable which is not instantiated. That is why the working solution uses the predicate `between/3`. Between assigns a value to a variable and enables the use of backtracking for finding multiple solutions.

**Note** : Using the `gtrace` command in swipl can help you in debugging your code!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using the library "CLP(FD) Constraint Logic Programming over Finite Domains".

:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

%% "How many men and horses have 8 heads and 20 feet?"

men_and_horses(Men, Horses):-
    Men in 0..10,
    Horses in 0..10,
    Men + Horses #= 8, %% heads must be 8
    Men * 2 + Horses * 4 #= 20. %% feet mus be 20

The solution is

?- men_and_horses(X,Y).
X = 6,
Y = 2.